# Pi zero 2 W capable to drive 1440x2880 HDMI display 35hz

Tags: pi-zero-w, display

I need to run following Wisecoco flex OLED HDMI display 144üx2880 35Hz o
PI ZERO 2 W ....
Maybe running loswerden resolution or othersegup, if thedisplay and Pi can manage?

Display is:
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/4000844224396.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.5.5afc1802MTAw3Z&gatewayAdapt=glo2deu

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? ... what is your question?